How can I invoke Steam for Linux in GDB *via its `.desktop` file*?
Problem
steam-1.0.0.82-1.fc41.i686 from RPMFusion is crashing for me upon startup (when invoked from $HOME/.local/share/applications/steam.desktop). An example of this is visible at youtu.be/jZQqvgGneSc.
As the undermentioned .KCrash file demonstrates drkonqi-coredump-gui doesn't produce a useful trace for it:
           PID: 160667 (steamwebhelper)
           UID: 1000 (RokeJulianLockhart)
           GID: 1000 (RokeJulianLockhart)
        Signal: 11 (SEGV)
     Timestamp: Tue 2024-12-03 17:56:53 GMT (3h 37min ago)
  Command Line: ./steamwebhelper -lang=en_US -cachedir=/home/RokeJulianLockhart/.local/share/Steam/config/htmlcache -steampid=159838 -buildid=1731433018 -steamid=76561198832168690 -logdir=/home/RokeJulianLockhart/.local/share/Steam/logs -uimode=7 -startcount=1 -steamuniverse=Public -realm=Global -clientui=/home/RokeJulianLockhart/.local/share/Steam/clientui -steampath=/home/RokeJulianLockhart/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam -launcher=0 -no-restart-on-ui-mode-change --valve-enable-site-isolation --enable-smooth-scrolling --password-store=basic --log-file=/home/RokeJulianLockhart/.local/share/Steam/logs/cef_log.txt --disable-quick-menu --enable-features=PlatformHEVCDecoderSupport --disable-features=SpareRendererForSitePerProcess,DcheckIsFatal,ValveFFmpegAllowLowDelayHEVC
    Executable: /home/RokeJulianLockhart/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_64/steamwebhelper
 Control Group: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/app-steam@16d13b83ca27431bab21f6fb66833e8e.service
          Unit: user@1000.service
     User Unit: app-steam@16d13b83ca27431bab21f6fb66833e8e.service
         Slice: user-1000.slice
     Owner UID: 1000 (RokeJulianLockhart)
       Boot ID: c12448e213c144b18ffc5a0816158a6a
    Machine ID: 8962ec69d8de46f6b8ebc778a4ca76cb
      Hostname: SNRW3Q
       Storage: /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.steamwebhelper.1000.c12448e213c144b18ffc5a0816158a6a.160667.1733248613000000.zst (present)
  Size on Disk: 6.6M
       Message: Process 160667 (steamwebhelper) of user 1000 dumped core.
                
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0 from rpm libxcb-1.17.0-3.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libGLX_mesa.so.0.0.0 from rpm mesa-24.2.8-1.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0 from rpm libXxf86vm-1.1.5-7.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libudev.so.1.7.9 from rpm systemd-256.9-2.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libcap.so.2.70 from rpm libcap-2.70-4.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libwayland-client.so.0.23.0 from rpm wayland-1.23.0-2.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2.12.8 from rpm libxml2-2.12.8-2.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libunistring.so.5.0.0 from rpm libunistring-1.1-8.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libedit.so.0.0.74 from rpm libedit-3.1-53.20240808cvs.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libpciaccess.so.0.11.1 from rpm libpciaccess-0.16-13.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libffi.so.8.1.4 from rpm libffi-3.4.6-3.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libxcb-dri2.so.0.0.0 from rpm libxcb-1.17.0-3.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libdrm_intel.so.1.123.0 from rpm libdrm-2.4.123-1.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libdrm_amdgpu.so.1.123.0 from rpm libdrm-2.4.123-1.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libelf-0.192.so from rpm elfutils-0.192-6.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libdrm_radeon.so.1.123.0 from rpm libdrm-2.4.123-1.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libsensors.so.4.5.0 from rpm lm_sensors-3.6.0-20.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libxshmfence.so.1.0.0 from rpm libxshmfence-1.3.2-5.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libxcb-sync.so.1.0.0 from rpm libxcb-1.17.0-3.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libxcb-xfixes.so.0.0.0 from rpm libxcb-1.17.0-3.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libxcb-present.so.0.0.0 from rpm libxcb-1.17.0-3.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libxcb-dri3.so.0.1.0 from rpm libxcb-1.17.0-3.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0 from rpm libX11-1.8.10-2.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libglapi.so.0.0.0 from rpm mesa-24.2.8-1.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libidn2.so.0.4.0 from rpm libidn2-2.3.7-2.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libzstd.so.1.5.6 from rpm zstd-1.5.6-2.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5.6.2 from rpm xz-5.6.2-2.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libgallium-24.2.8.so from rpm mesa-24.2.8-1.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libxcb-shm.so.0.0.0 from rpm libxcb-1.17.0-3.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libxcb-randr.so.0.1.0 from rpm libxcb-1.17.0-3.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libwayland-server.so.0.23.0 from rpm wayland-1.23.0-2.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libXau.so.6.0.0 from rpm libXau-1.0.11-7.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libGLdispatch.so.0.0.0 from rpm libglvnd-1.7.0-5.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libGLX.so.0.0.0 from rpm libglvnd-1.7.0-5.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libz.so.1.3.1.zlib-ng from rpm zlib-ng-2.1.7-3.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libgbm.so.1.0.0 from rpm mesa-24.2.8-1.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1.1.0 from rpm libxcb-1.17.0-3.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libexpat.so.1.10.0 from rpm expat-2.6.4-1.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libXfixes.so.3.1.0 from rpm libXfixes-6.0.1-4.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libdrm.so.2.123.0 from rpm libdrm-2.4.123-1.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libGL.so.1.7.0 from rpm libglvnd-1.7.0-5.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libX11.so.6.4.0 from rpm libX11-1.8.10-2.fc41.x86_64
                Module /run/host/usr/lib64/libXext.so.6.4.0 from rpm libXext-1.3.6-2.fc41.x86_64
                Stack trace of thread 160771:
                #0  0x0000000000000000 n/a (n/a + 0x0)
                ELF object binary architecture: AMD x86-64


I presume that this is due to the undermentioned:
RokeJulianLockhart@SNRW3Q:~$ file /usr/bin/steam
/usr/bin/steam: symbolic link to /usr/lib/steam/bin_steam.sh
RokeJulianLockhart@SNRW3Q:~$ file /usr/lib/steam/bin_steam.sh
/usr/lib/steam/bin_steam.sh: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable

Consequently, I want to capture a stack trace (using gdb), so that I can report this crash to bugzilla.rpmfusion.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Fedora. (It's not a duplicate of /show_bug.cgi?id=6900#c6.)
Preventing me doing is so, is that, incredibly, it does not crash when invoked via bash (in konsole):
#!/usr/bin/env -S bash
steam

That inability to make it crash in the shell is why I'm unable to debug the source of it crashing, because the undermentioned is of no use:
#!/usr/bin/env -S bash
DEBUGGER=gdb steam

Attempted Solutions
Consequently, I have attempted to add the diagnostic information to its .desktop file. To demonstrate what I have modified, by default, its content is the undermentioned:
[Desktop Action BigPicture]
Exec=steam steam://open/bigpicture
Name=Big Picture

[Desktop Action Community]
Exec=steam steam://url/SteamIDControlPage
Name=Community
Name[bg]=Общност
Name[cs]=Komunita
Name[da]=Fællesskab
Name[de]=Community
Name[el]=Κοινότητα
Name[es]=Comunidad
Name[fi]=Yhteisö
Name[fr]=Communauté
Name[hu]=Közösség
Name[it]=Comunità
Name[ja]=コミュニティ
Name[ko]=커뮤니티
Name[nl]=Community
Name[no]=Samfunn
Name[pl]=Społeczność
Name[pt_BR]=Comunidade
Name[pt_PT]=Comunidade
Name[ro]=Comunitate
Name[ru]=Сообщество
Name[sv]=Gemenskap
Name[th]=ชุมชน
Name[tr]=Topluluk
Name[uk]=Спільнота
Name[vi]=Cộng đồng
Name[zh_CN]=社区
Name[zh_TW]=社群

[Desktop Action Friends]
Exec=steam steam://open/friends
Name=Friends
Name[bg]=Приятели
Name[cs]=Přátelé
Name[da]=Venner
Name[de]=Freunde
Name[el]=Φίλοι
Name[es]=Amigos
Name[fi]=Kaverit
Name[fr]=Amis
Name[hu]=Barátok
Name[it]=Amici
Name[ja]=フレンド
Name[ko]=친구
Name[nl]=Vrienden
Name[no]=Venner
Name[pl]=Znajomi
Name[pt_BR]=Amigos
Name[pt_PT]=Amigos
Name[ro]=Prieteni
Name[ru]=Друзья
Name[sv]=Vänner
Name[th]=เพื่อน
Name[tr]=Arkadaşlar
Name[uk]=Друзі
Name[vi]=Bạn bè
Name[zh_CN]=好友
Name[zh_TW]=好友

[Desktop Action Library]
Exec=steam steam://open/games
Name=Library
Name[bg]=Библиотека
Name[cs]=Knihovna
Name[da]=Bibliotek
Name[de]=Bibliothek
Name[el]=Συλλογή
Name[es]=Biblioteca
Name[fi]=Kokoelma
Name[fr]=Bibliothèque
Name[hu]=Könyvtár
Name[it]=Libreria
Name[ja]=ライブラリ
Name[ko]=라이브러리
Name[nl]=Bibliotheek
Name[no]=Bibliotek
Name[pl]=Biblioteka
Name[pt_BR]=Biblioteca
Name[pt_PT]=Biblioteca
Name[ro]=Colecţie
Name[ru]=Библиотека
Name[sv]=Bibliotek
Name[th]=คลัง
Name[tr]=Kütüphane
Name[uk]=Бібліотека
Name[vi]=Thư viện
Name[zh_CN]=库
Name[zh_TW]=收藏庫

[Desktop Action News]
Exec=steam steam://open/news
Name=News
Name[bg]=Новини
Name[cs]=Zprávy
Name[da]=Nyheder
Name[de]=Neuigkeiten
Name[el]=Νέα
Name[es]=Noticias
Name[fi]=Uutiset
Name[fr]=Actualités
Name[hu]=Hírek
Name[it]=Notizie
Name[ja]=ニュース
Name[ko]=뉴스
Name[nl]=Nieuws
Name[no]=Nyheter
Name[pl]=Aktualności
Name[pt_BR]=Notícias
Name[pt_PT]=Novidades
Name[ro]=Știri
Name[ru]=Новости
Name[sv]=Nyheter
Name[th]=ข่าวสาร
Name[tr]=Haberler
Name[uk]=Новини
Name[vi]=Tin tức
Name[zh_CN]=新闻
Name[zh_TW]=新聞

[Desktop Action Screenshots]
Exec=steam steam://open/screenshots
Name=Screenshots
Name[bg]=Снимки
Name[cs]=Snímky obrazovky
Name[da]=Skærmbilleder
Name[de]=Screenshots
Name[el]=Φωτογραφίες
Name[es]=Capturas
Name[fi]=Kuvankaappaukset
Name[fr]=Captures d'écran
Name[hu]=Képernyőmentések
Name[it]=Screenshot
Name[ja]=スクリーンショット
Name[ko]=스크린샷
Name[nl]=Screenshots
Name[no]=Skjermbilder
Name[pl]=Zrzuty ekranu
Name[pt_BR]=Capturas de tela
Name[pt_PT]=Capturas de ecrã
Name[ro]=Capturi de ecran
Name[ru]=Скриншоты
Name[sv]=Skärmdumpar
Name[th]=ภาพหน้าจอ
Name[tr]=Ekran Görüntüleri
Name[uk]=Скріншоти
Name[vi]=Ảnh chụp
Name[zh_CN]=截图
Name[zh_TW]=螢幕擷圖

[Desktop Action Servers]
Exec=steam steam://open/servers
Name=Servers
Name[bg]=Сървъри
Name[cs]=Servery
Name[da]=Servere
Name[de]=Server
Name[el]=Διακομιστές
Name[es]=Servidores
Name[fi]=Palvelimet
Name[fr]=Serveurs
Name[hu]=Szerverek
Name[it]=Server
Name[ja]=サーバー
Name[ko]=서버
Name[nl]=Servers
Name[no]=Tjenere
Name[pl]=Serwery
Name[pt_BR]=Servidores
Name[pt_PT]=Servidores
Name[ro]=Servere
Name[ru]=Серверы
Name[sv]=Servrar
Name[th]=เซิร์ฟเวอร์
Name[tr]=Sunucular
Name[uk]=Сервери
Name[vi]=Máy chủ
Name[zh_CN]=服务器
Name[zh_TW]=伺服器

[Desktop Action Settings]
Exec=steam steam://open/settings
Name=Settings
Name[bg]=Настройки
Name[cs]=Nastavení
Name[da]=Indstillinger
Name[de]=Einstellungen
Name[el]=Ρυθμίσεις
Name[es]=Parámetros
Name[fi]=Asetukset
Name[fr]=Paramètres
Name[hu]=Beállítások
Name[it]=Impostazioni
Name[ja]=設定
Name[ko]=설정
Name[nl]=Instellingen
Name[no]=Innstillinger
Name[pl]=Ustawienia
Name[pt_BR]=Configurações
Name[pt_PT]=Definições
Name[ro]=Setări
Name[ru]=Настройки
Name[sv]=Inställningar
Name[th]=การตั้งค่า
Name[tr]=Ayarlar
Name[uk]=Налаштування
Name[vi]=Thiết lập
Name[zh_CN]=设置
Name[zh_TW]=設定

[Desktop Action Store]
Exec=steam steam://store
Name=Store
Name[bg]=Магазин
Name[cs]=Obchod
Name[da]=Butik
Name[de]=Shop
Name[el]=ΚΑΤΑΣΤΗΜΑ
Name[es]=Tienda
Name[fi]=Kauppa
Name[fr]=Magasin
Name[hu]=Áruház
Name[it]=Negozio
Name[ja]=ストア
Name[ko]=상점
Name[nl]=Winkel
Name[no]=Butikk
Name[pl]=Sklep
Name[pt_BR]=Loja
Name[pt_PT]=Loja
Name[ro]=Magazin
Name[ru]=Магазин
Name[sv]=Butik
Name[th]=ร้านค้า
Name[tr]=Mağaza
Name[uk]=Крамниця
Name[vi]=Cửa hàng
Name[zh_CN]=商店
Name[zh_TW]=商店

[Desktop Entry]
Actions=Store;Community;Library;Servers;Screenshots;News;Settings;BigPicture;Friends;
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;Game;
Comment[en_GB]=Application for managing and playing games on Steam
Comment=Application for managing and playing games on Steam
Comment[bg]=Приложение за ръководене и пускане на игри в Steam
Comment[cs]=Aplikace pro spravování a hraní her ve službě Steam
Comment[da]=Applikation til at håndtere og spille spil på Steam
Comment[de]=Anwendung zum Verwalten und Spielen von Spielen auf Steam
Comment[el]=Εφαρμογή διαχείρισης παιχνιδιών στο Steam
Comment[es]=Aplicación para administrar y ejecutar juegos en Steam
Comment[fi]=Steamin pelien hallintaan ja pelaamiseen tarkoitettu sovellus
Comment[fr]=Application de gestion et d'utilisation des jeux sur Steam
Comment[hu]=Alkalmazás a Steames játékok futtatásához és kezeléséhez
Comment[it]=Applicazione per la gestione e l'esecuzione di giochi su Steam
Comment[ja]=Steam 上でゲームを管理＆プレイするためのアプリケーション
Comment[ko]=Steam에 있는 게임을 관리하고 플레이할 수 있는 응용 프로그램
Comment[nl]=Applicatie voor het beheer en het spelen van games op Steam
Comment[no]=Program for å administrere og spille spill på Steam
Comment[pl]=Aplikacja do zarządzania i uruchamiania gier na platformie Steam
Comment[pt_BR]=Aplicativo para jogar e gerenciar jogos no Steam
Comment[pt_PT]=Aplicação para organizar e executar jogos no Steam
Comment[ro]=Aplicație pentru administrarea și jucatul jocurilor pe Steam
Comment[ru]=Приложение для игр и управления играми в Steam
Comment[sv]=Ett program för att hantera samt spela spel på Steam
Comment[th]=โปรแกรมสำหรับจัดการและเล่นเกมบน Steam
Comment[tr]=Steam üzerinden oyun oynama ve düzenleme uygulaması
Comment[uk]=Програма для керування іграми та запуску ігор у Steam
Comment[vi]=Ứng dụng để quản lý và chơi trò chơi trên Steam
Comment[zh_CN]=管理和进行 Steam 游戏的应用程序
Comment[zh_TW]=管理並執行 Steam 遊戲的應用程式
Exec=env /usr/bin/steam %U
GenericName[en_GB]=
GenericName=
Icon=steam
MimeType=
Name[en_GB]=Steam
Name=Steam
Path=
PrefersNonDefaultGPU=true
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
TerminalOptions=\s--noclose
Type=Application
X-KDE-RunOnDiscreteGpu=true
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
X-KDE-Username=


I then modify it as the undermentioned demonstrate:


- Exec=env /usr/bin/steam %U
+ Exec=env 'DEBUGGER=gdb --args /usr/bin/steam' %U



- Terminal=false
+ Terminal=true



This becomes the undermentioned:
[Desktop Action BigPicture]
Exec=steam steam://open/bigpicture
Name=Big Picture

[Desktop Action Community]
Exec=steam steam://url/SteamIDControlPage
Name=Community
Name[bg]=Общност
Name[cs]=Komunita
Name[da]=Fællesskab
Name[de]=Community
Name[el]=Κοινότητα
Name[es]=Comunidad
Name[fi]=Yhteisö
Name[fr]=Communauté
Name[hu]=Közösség
Name[it]=Comunità
Name[ja]=コミュニティ
Name[ko]=커뮤니티
Name[nl]=Community
Name[no]=Samfunn
Name[pl]=Społeczność
Name[pt_BR]=Comunidade
Name[pt_PT]=Comunidade
Name[ro]=Comunitate
Name[ru]=Сообщество
Name[sv]=Gemenskap
Name[th]=ชุมชน
Name[tr]=Topluluk
Name[uk]=Спільнота
Name[vi]=Cộng đồng
Name[zh_CN]=社区
Name[zh_TW]=社群

[Desktop Action Friends]
Exec=steam steam://open/friends
Name=Friends
Name[bg]=Приятели
Name[cs]=Přátelé
Name[da]=Venner
Name[de]=Freunde
Name[el]=Φίλοι
Name[es]=Amigos
Name[fi]=Kaverit
Name[fr]=Amis
Name[hu]=Barátok
Name[it]=Amici
Name[ja]=フレンド
Name[ko]=친구
Name[nl]=Vrienden
Name[no]=Venner
Name[pl]=Znajomi
Name[pt_BR]=Amigos
Name[pt_PT]=Amigos
Name[ro]=Prieteni
Name[ru]=Друзья
Name[sv]=Vänner
Name[th]=เพื่อน
Name[tr]=Arkadaşlar
Name[uk]=Друзі
Name[vi]=Bạn bè
Name[zh_CN]=好友
Name[zh_TW]=好友

[Desktop Action Library]
Exec=steam steam://open/games
Name=Library
Name[bg]=Библиотека
Name[cs]=Knihovna
Name[da]=Bibliotek
Name[de]=Bibliothek
Name[el]=Συλλογή
Name[es]=Biblioteca
Name[fi]=Kokoelma
Name[fr]=Bibliothèque
Name[hu]=Könyvtár
Name[it]=Libreria
Name[ja]=ライブラリ
Name[ko]=라이브러리
Name[nl]=Bibliotheek
Name[no]=Bibliotek
Name[pl]=Biblioteka
Name[pt_BR]=Biblioteca
Name[pt_PT]=Biblioteca
Name[ro]=Colecţie
Name[ru]=Библиотека
Name[sv]=Bibliotek
Name[th]=คลัง
Name[tr]=Kütüphane
Name[uk]=Бібліотека
Name[vi]=Thư viện
Name[zh_CN]=库
Name[zh_TW]=收藏庫

[Desktop Action News]
Exec=steam steam://open/news
Name=News
Name[bg]=Новини
Name[cs]=Zprávy
Name[da]=Nyheder
Name[de]=Neuigkeiten
Name[el]=Νέα
Name[es]=Noticias
Name[fi]=Uutiset
Name[fr]=Actualités
Name[hu]=Hírek
Name[it]=Notizie
Name[ja]=ニュース
Name[ko]=뉴스
Name[nl]=Nieuws
Name[no]=Nyheter
Name[pl]=Aktualności
Name[pt_BR]=Notícias
Name[pt_PT]=Novidades
Name[ro]=Știri
Name[ru]=Новости
Name[sv]=Nyheter
Name[th]=ข่าวสาร
Name[tr]=Haberler
Name[uk]=Новини
Name[vi]=Tin tức
Name[zh_CN]=新闻
Name[zh_TW]=新聞

[Desktop Action Screenshots]
Exec=steam steam://open/screenshots
Name=Screenshots
Name[bg]=Снимки
Name[cs]=Snímky obrazovky
Name[da]=Skærmbilleder
Name[de]=Screenshots
Name[el]=Φωτογραφίες
Name[es]=Capturas
Name[fi]=Kuvankaappaukset
Name[fr]=Captures d'écran
Name[hu]=Képernyőmentések
Name[it]=Screenshot
Name[ja]=スクリーンショット
Name[ko]=스크린샷
Name[nl]=Screenshots
Name[no]=Skjermbilder
Name[pl]=Zrzuty ekranu
Name[pt_BR]=Capturas de tela
Name[pt_PT]=Capturas de ecrã
Name[ro]=Capturi de ecran
Name[ru]=Скриншоты
Name[sv]=Skärmdumpar
Name[th]=ภาพหน้าจอ
Name[tr]=Ekran Görüntüleri
Name[uk]=Скріншоти
Name[vi]=Ảnh chụp
Name[zh_CN]=截图
Name[zh_TW]=螢幕擷圖

[Desktop Action Servers]
Exec=steam steam://open/servers
Name=Servers
Name[bg]=Сървъри
Name[cs]=Servery
Name[da]=Servere
Name[de]=Server
Name[el]=Διακομιστές
Name[es]=Servidores
Name[fi]=Palvelimet
Name[fr]=Serveurs
Name[hu]=Szerverek
Name[it]=Server
Name[ja]=サーバー
Name[ko]=서버
Name[nl]=Servers
Name[no]=Tjenere
Name[pl]=Serwery
Name[pt_BR]=Servidores
Name[pt_PT]=Servidores
Name[ro]=Servere
Name[ru]=Серверы
Name[sv]=Servrar
Name[th]=เซิร์ฟเวอร์
Name[tr]=Sunucular
Name[uk]=Сервери
Name[vi]=Máy chủ
Name[zh_CN]=服务器
Name[zh_TW]=伺服器

[Desktop Action Settings]
Exec=steam steam://open/settings
Name=Settings
Name[bg]=Настройки
Name[cs]=Nastavení
Name[da]=Indstillinger
Name[de]=Einstellungen
Name[el]=Ρυθμίσεις
Name[es]=Parámetros
Name[fi]=Asetukset
Name[fr]=Paramètres
Name[hu]=Beállítások
Name[it]=Impostazioni
Name[ja]=設定
Name[ko]=설정
Name[nl]=Instellingen
Name[no]=Innstillinger
Name[pl]=Ustawienia
Name[pt_BR]=Configurações
Name[pt_PT]=Definições
Name[ro]=Setări
Name[ru]=Настройки
Name[sv]=Inställningar
Name[th]=การตั้งค่า
Name[tr]=Ayarlar
Name[uk]=Налаштування
Name[vi]=Thiết lập
Name[zh_CN]=设置
Name[zh_TW]=設定

[Desktop Action Store]
Exec=steam steam://store
Name=Store
Name[bg]=Магазин
Name[cs]=Obchod
Name[da]=Butik
Name[de]=Shop
Name[el]=ΚΑΤΑΣΤΗΜΑ
Name[es]=Tienda
Name[fi]=Kauppa
Name[fr]=Magasin
Name[hu]=Áruház
Name[it]=Negozio
Name[ja]=ストア
Name[ko]=상점
Name[nl]=Winkel
Name[no]=Butikk
Name[pl]=Sklep
Name[pt_BR]=Loja
Name[pt_PT]=Loja
Name[ro]=Magazin
Name[ru]=Магазин
Name[sv]=Butik
Name[th]=ร้านค้า
Name[tr]=Mağaza
Name[uk]=Крамниця
Name[vi]=Cửa hàng
Name[zh_CN]=商店
Name[zh_TW]=商店

[Desktop Entry]
Actions=Store;Community;Library;Servers;Screenshots;News;Settings;BigPicture;Friends;
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;Game;
Comment[en_GB]=Application for managing and playing games on Steam
Comment=Application for managing and playing games on Steam
Comment[bg]=Приложение за ръководене и пускане на игри в Steam
Comment[cs]=Aplikace pro spravování a hraní her ve službě Steam
Comment[da]=Applikation til at håndtere og spille spil på Steam
Comment[de]=Anwendung zum Verwalten und Spielen von Spielen auf Steam
Comment[el]=Εφαρμογή διαχείρισης παιχνιδιών στο Steam
Comment[es]=Aplicación para administrar y ejecutar juegos en Steam
Comment[fi]=Steamin pelien hallintaan ja pelaamiseen tarkoitettu sovellus
Comment[fr]=Application de gestion et d'utilisation des jeux sur Steam
Comment[hu]=Alkalmazás a Steames játékok futtatásához és kezeléséhez
Comment[it]=Applicazione per la gestione e l'esecuzione di giochi su Steam
Comment[ja]=Steam 上でゲームを管理＆プレイするためのアプリケーション
Comment[ko]=Steam에 있는 게임을 관리하고 플레이할 수 있는 응용 프로그램
Comment[nl]=Applicatie voor het beheer en het spelen van games op Steam
Comment[no]=Program for å administrere og spille spill på Steam
Comment[pl]=Aplikacja do zarządzania i uruchamiania gier na platformie Steam
Comment[pt_BR]=Aplicativo para jogar e gerenciar jogos no Steam
Comment[pt_PT]=Aplicação para organizar e executar jogos no Steam
Comment[ro]=Aplicație pentru administrarea și jucatul jocurilor pe Steam
Comment[ru]=Приложение для игр и управления играми в Steam
Comment[sv]=Ett program för att hantera samt spela spel på Steam
Comment[th]=โปรแกรมสำหรับจัดการและเล่นเกมบน Steam
Comment[tr]=Steam üzerinden oyun oynama ve düzenleme uygulaması
Comment[uk]=Програма для керування іграми та запуску ігор у Steam
Comment[vi]=Ứng dụng để quản lý và chơi trò chơi trên Steam
Comment[zh_CN]=管理和进行 Steam 游戏的应用程序
Comment[zh_TW]=管理並執行 Steam 遊戲的應用程式
Exec=env 'DEBUGGER=gdb --args /usr/bin/steam' %U
GenericName[en_GB]=
GenericName=
Icon=steam
MimeType=
Name[en_GB]=Steam
Name=Steam
Path=
PrefersNonDefaultGPU=true
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=true
TerminalOptions=\s--noclose
Type=Application
X-KDE-RunOnDiscreteGpu=true
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
X-KDE-Username=


The aforementioned doesn't work, for although Terminal=true makes me see that the variable has been passed, I do not see the gdb CLI:

Potential Solutions
I may be able to spawn an interactive shell by using the instructions in /revisions/682872/4. However, I don't much understand them; much less so, how to implement them in a .desktop file.
Corroborations
This situation appears to be similar to bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=295425. However, their solution is irrelevant to mine, because I've no NVIDIA hardware.

Can I know why the downvote? I can't improve the question without a reason.

This doesn't answer the question asked, but this does provide the solution to what I wanted to diagnose: disable GPU acceleration for the GUI:

